# FirebaseTranslatorOptions.Builder object is not taking input from dropdownmenu (Spinner) Firebase Translate text in Android

Tags: android, firebase, spinner, firebase-mlkit

I have developed an App in Android which translates text (from EditText), Application uses Firebase API. it translates successfully when I select Source and Target Language in hard code. (FirebaseTranslatorOption's setSource and setTarget language settings even integer code i.e. EN (11), FR(17) etc. but it is not taking any dynamic input from Spinner object's setOnItemSelectedListener. 
'''
        //Spinners itemselection events

```
    input_lang_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
                    "OnItemSelectedListener : " + parent.getItemAtPosition(position),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            selected_source_lang = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Plz select a language",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                case 1:
                       SourceLangCode=11;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    SourceLangCode=17;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    SourceLangCode=56;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    SourceLangCode=48;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    SourceLangCode=9;
                    break;
            }
        }

   @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Plz select a language",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

//end of input language selection

```
 output_lang_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
                    "OnItemSelectedListener : " + parent.getItemAtPosition(position),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            selected_target_lang = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Plz select a       language",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                case 1:
                    targetLangCode=11;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    targetLangCode=17;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    targetLangCode=56;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    targetLangCode=48;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    targetLangCode=9;
                    break;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Plz select a language",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });//end of output language selection
```

//firebaseTranslatorOptions object

```
    FirebaseTranslatorOptions options =
            new FirebaseTranslatorOptions.Builder()
                    .setSourceLanguage(SourceLangCode)  //this is not taken as I select item
                    .setTargetLanguage(targetLangCode)   //item selection is working
                    .build();

    final FirebaseTranslator languageTranslator =
            FirebaseNaturalLanguage.getInstance().getTranslator(options);
```

'''

Comment: have to check that before `setSourceLanguage` is `SourceLangCode` has the correct value

Comment: I have tested Item selection gives correct index and setting Source and Target language integer variables correctly.

Comment: then I can't help you because I havent tried FirebaseTranslator

Comment: #Burhan Khanzada thanks anyway,but I wonder not a single person here to help.